# AWS API Gateway GET Method Fail

Tags: amazon-web-services, web-applications, aws-api-gateway

I have been trying for a really long time now to get my GET method on API Gateway going and hopefully, someone here can help me.

Let me give you a lay of the land: I have an HTML Website in an S3 bucket. On the website, I have a button which calls an API from AWS API Gateway in order to get me some data from a DynamoDB via a Lambda function. 
When pressing the button the user on the website sends the following AJAX call:

```js
$.ajax({
    method: 'GET',
    url: /*my API Link*/ ,
    headers: {
      Authorization: authToken
    },
    contentType: 'application/json',
    success: function(data) {
      alert(JSON.stringify(data))
    });
}
```

The call includes a token generated from AWS Cognito. When testing the token separately if works without any issues.

In API Gateway I have created the GET method accordingly, together with the authorization for the token and the user pool. The Integration request refers to the correct Lambda function and I have chosen "Use Lambda Proxy Integration". When clicking the button I can see that the Lambda function gets called and executes as it is supposed to in CloudWatch.

However, now the problem, I do not get the data back from the Lambda function. In the console from Chrome I get the following error message:

```
Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 403 ()
xxx.html:1 
Failed to load https://xxx.amazonaws.com/prod: Response to preflight 
the request doesn't pass access control check: No 'Access-Control-Allow- 
Origin' header is present on the requested resource. Origin 'https://s3- 
eu-west-2.amazonaws.com' is therefore not allowed access. The response 
had HTTP status code 403.
```

I have enabled CORS before deploying the API. Can anybody help with this problem?

Comment: This would be expected if you did not have the *correct* origin configured in the API Gateway CORS configuration.  According to the error, that value should be `https://s3- 
eu-west-2.amazonaws.com` -- although that, in turn, suggests other problems.

Comment: "Response to preflight 
the request doesn't pass access control check: No 'Access-Control-Allow- 
Origin' header is present on the requested resource" -- error suggest that preflight request failed. Which will happen if you have not setup ( or correctly setup ) OPTIONS method with Mock integration in your API. See how to setup OPTIONS https://docs.aws.amazon.com/apigateway/latest/developerguide/how-to-cors.html